# Subtracting function using different rows and columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   ROW     ID   ORDER       START      FINISH
    1      A      1           0            1
    2      A      1           2            4
    3      B      1           0            2
    4      A      2           4            5
    5      B      2           2            5
    6      B      2           6            8
```

I wanna create a new column that for each row subtracts something like:

```
START[x] - FINISH[x-1]
```

where x is the ROW and returns NA if ORDER or ID is changed so that will be the result: (consider dataframe ordered by ORDER than by ID)

```
  ROW     ID   ORDER         START       FINISH      NEW
    1      A      1           0            1        NA (first value) 
    2      A      1           2            4          1
    3      B      1           0            2        NA(changed ID) 
    4      A      2           4            5        NA(changed Order) 
    5      B      2           2            3        NA(changed ID) 
    6      B      2           6            8          3
```

I'm new to R so I can't figure out how to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dplyr, this is a grouped `mutate`, lagging `FINISH`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(ROW = 1:6, 
                 ID = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B"), 
                 ORDER = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                 START = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 6L), 
                 FINISH = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 8L))

df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(ID, ORDER) %>% 
    mutate(NEW = START - lag(FINISH))

df2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID, ORDER [4]
#>     ROW ID    ORDER START FINISH   NEW
#>   <int> <chr> <int> <int>  <int> <int>
#> 1     1 A         1     0      1    NA
#> 2     2 A         1     2      4     1
#> 3     3 B         1     0      2    NA
#> 4     4 A         2     4      5    NA
#> 5     5 B         2     2      5    NA
#> 6     6 B         2     6      8     1
```

You can do the same thing in base R with a split-apply-combine approach, though it doesn't read as nicely:

```r
df2 <- do.call(rbind, 
               lapply(split(df, interaction(df$ID, df$ORDER)), 
                      function(x){
                          x$NEW <- x$START - c(NA, x$FINISH[-nrow(x)]); 
                          x
                      }))

df2
#>       ROW ID ORDER START FINISH NEW
#> A.1.1   1  A     1     0      1  NA
#> A.1.2   2  A     1     2      4   1
#> B.1     3  B     1     0      2  NA
#> A.2     4  A     2     4      5  NA
#> B.2.5   5  B     2     2      5  NA
#> B.2.6   6  B     2     6      8   1
```

Note that the fifth element of `FINISH` varies in the input and output data in the question, which is why the result of `NEW` varies in row 6. The logic holds, though.

Comment: Why in your answers you group by ID, ORDER and it works, although to work ORDER must be the main ordering and then ID?

Comment: There isn't a "main ordering"; each grouping variable is treated equivalently. If you look at what `interaction` does in the base version, that's effectively what's happening: it's creating a group for each observed combination of `ID` and `ORDER`.

Comment: Is that because is internally subsetting by order and id but that's "invisible" so is a subsetting and not an ordering?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Despite the variable name, there isn't any ordering happening in the code. There isn't exactly subsetting, either; it's splitting.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion the variable ORDER is a commercial order, I mean ordering in sense of sorting, anyway I get it

Answer (score 0):

with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,NEW := START-shift(FINISH),by=.(ID,ORDER)]

#    ROW ID ORDER START FINISH NEW
# 1:   1  A     1     0      1  NA
# 2:   2  A     1     2      4   1
# 3:   3  B     1     0      2  NA
# 4:   4  A     2     4      5  NA
# 5:   5  B     2     2      5  NA
# 6:   6  B     2     6      8   1
```